# Targeting a specific class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display a hidden class in jQuery but it is no applying to the class I am targeting. It displays the whole class:

```
<div class="feeds">
  <input class="post_id" />
  <textarea class="commentdata"></textarea>
  <button class="mmore">More</button>
  <p class="time">time</p>
  <div class = "comment_data">
    <div class = "comment">
      <p> Comments </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="feeds">
  <input class="post_id" />
  <textarea class="commentdata"></textarea>
  <button class="mmore">More</button>
  <p class="time">time</p>
  <div class = "comment_data">
    <div class = "comment">
      <p> Comments </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
<div class="feeds">
  <input class="post_id" />
  <textarea class="commentdata"></textarea>
  <button class="mmore">More</button>
  <p class="time">time</p>
  <div class = "comment_data">
    <div class = "comment">
      <p> Comments </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The class `comment_data` is `display: none` by default and should only be displayed whenever the **More** button is clicked. Working but it is displaying all the comments for 3 `div`.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$( ".mmore" ).click(function() {
   $('.comment_data').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.mmore').click(function() {
   $(this).parents('.feeds').find('.comment_data').slideToggle('slow')
});
```

Comment: This is more convenient because it less depends on html structure.

Comment: This did the trick. You've just sealed my day productively. Thanks a whole lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.closest()` to find *.feeds* div and then use `.find()` for *.comment_data* div

```
$('.mmore').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('.feeds').find('.comment_data').slideToggle('slow')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting all objects matching the selector `.comment_data`.

You'll need to limit it to the same container that the clicked button is in. There's a number of ways you could do this.  One easy one would be:

```
$( ".mmore" ).click(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('.comment_data').slideToggle("slow");
});
```